# Drupal - moving module folder

Tags: drupal, module

Is it safe to move my modules

- From *sites/all/modules/*
- To *sites/all/modules/contrib* and *sites/all/modules/custom*

on a production site?

That is, does Drupal automatically detect that the module is still there, but in a new path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move a module Drupal will see that the old one is broken, and a new one exists.  It will not assume the two are the same thing - simply moved.

Comment: If you disable the module, move it, then re-enable it at the new location you should be fine.  It'll probably keep its settings.  If you simply yank it out from underneath Drupal it won't like that.

Comment: Step 1: Move the module. Step 2: Clear the cache. If a module stays broken at this point, there is a bug.

Comment: Additionally in Drupal 7, you may encounter problems with the registry after moving modules.

Follow the instructions at the following URL if you encounter this:

http://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild

Answer (score 21):

Drupal versions up to D6 kept module location in the system table, but starting from D7 there're multiple places where path is recorded (e.g. `registry` and `registry_file` tables) so just moving the folder and clearing cache will not do it, most probably will lead to significant problems.

A sequence of steps you can try:

1. Backup your database
2. Check-in your code into version control
3. Run following queries:

   ```
   UPDATE system
   SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/contrib');

   UPDATE registry
   SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/contrib');

   UPDATE registry_file
   SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/contrib')
   ```
4. Move folders
5. Run: `drush cc all`

Comment: when (5) gives errors (context gives errors), try to truncate all your cache% tables

Answer (score 3):

irakli's answer worked well for me, but I wanted to add some additional complexity to the queries in case others find them useful.

Step 1 – Update all 'custom' modules if you're lucky enough to have them sharing a namespace:

```
UPDATE system SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/custom') WHERE name LIKE 'custom_namespace_%';
UPDATE registry SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/custom') WHERE name LIKE 'custom_namespace_%';
UPDATE registry_file SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/custom') WHERE filename LIKE '%custom_namespace_%';
```

Step 2 - Update all 'dev' modules:

```
UPDATE system SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/dev') WHERE name LIKE 'devel%';
UPDATE registry SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/dev') WHERE name LIKE 'devel%';
UPDATE registry_file SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/dev') WHERE filename LIKE '%devel%';
```

Step 3 - Update all 'contrib' modules:

```
UPDATE system SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/contrib');
UPDATE registry SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/contrib');
UPDATE registry_file SET filename = REPLACE(filename, 'sites/all/modules', 'sites/all/modules/contrib')
```

Then throw all of your modules into the appropriate `sites/all/modules/contrib|custom|dev` folders, clear your cache, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal stores the file location in the system table, the info will be rebuilt when you clear the module cache, so if you move the stuff and clear the cache afterwards you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on D7, then this drupal documentation page is the best way to go ahead with moving modules around - [How to move modules and themes](https://drupal.org/node/183681)

Answer (score 1):

It's good to have /contrib and /custom subfolder for the modules. For D7, specially if you use entity, you should disable the modules, move them and then re-enable. It works.

The alternative, move the modules to the subfolders and clear cache, sometimes doesn't work and may generate WSOD.

Answer (score 1):

use http://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild
"Registry Rebuild will also rebuild the system table to get the modules in the right place so you can bootstrap."

- backup the db
- uploaded the 'module'
- moved all the modules
- run the script sites/all/modules/registry_rebuild/registry_rebuild.php
- reload the site
- if you get an error clear the browser cache and all is working again

Answer (score 1):

Actually you only need to do the update on the system table and then do the following:

```
drush rr
```

and maybe..

```
drush cc all

drush rr
```

Answer (score 1):

dont forget to use this module after changing the modules folder :

https://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild

Answer (score 0):

You can move most of the modules safely, if you clear the cache afterwards (drush cc all).

*However*, some modules, especially ctools, store file path information in places other than the system table or caches. You may have to leave those modules in their original location, but you can still move everything else.